# Easiest way to edit associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have what I imagine must be a common situation, but possibly can't find the way to phrase the question to get the solution...

I have a couple of linked models in my application:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :prod_code
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In fact there are a number of other models which also belong to Product.  By default, on the stock record, I just see the product_id field, which is an auto-incrementing number that isn't much help to the user.  Products have a unique `prod_code` which is on barcodes etc. and is the natural key of the product database.

What I would like is for the create/edit screens for the stock and other linked models to show a text field for the prod_code, and to be able to respond to parameters in the form `stock[prod_code]` in a sensible way (e.g. look up the prod_code, and set the prod_id based on the result), and automagically (e.g. `Stock.new(params[:stock])` should work.

To clarify, setting stock[prod_code] would not change anything in the product database; it would instead change the product_id for the relevant stock record i.e. link the stock record to a different product record.

At present, I've got various methods defined in the stock model such as `prod_code=` that make this work.  But as I mentioned, there are actually multiple models that refer back to my products table.  Is there any way I can define something inside the Product model?

e.g. something like a referenced_by method that would tell all linked models to deal with the `prod_code` argument by looking it up in the products table?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :prod_code
  referenced_by :prod_code
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you do with the nested product code; it's presented in the form as a text field - does that mean it's entered manually? Anyhow, accepts_nested_attributes I think is what you're looking for, though I think you'd have to set up a has_one relationship from Stock to Product http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: It looks to me like nested attributes are for e.g. editing the product code database from the stock screens.  This isn't what I want to do - I simply want to allow the user to enter a new product code on the stock edit screen.

Comment: The idea would be that I could go into the scaffolded views, and e.g. in _form.html.erb, change :product_id to :prod_code, and everything would work.  The edit screen would show the current product code, a user could type in a new one.

Comment: In answer to second comment - That's what I would imagine but I don't really understand. Stock belongs to product and you want to be able to assign or update which product, it would seem to me you probably would be better have a select list as part of your form where the user is presented the name of product but the form submits the product_id field of Stock. I guess what's confusing is what's prod_code?

Comment: Sorry, prod_code is just a unique code that identifies the product (it is in the barcode on all stock units, so the users can just scan it in).  A dropdown does make a lot of sense in some cases - it is exactly how I handle quality codes etc. but, there are 200,000 products.  Instead of letting the client side map from friendly name to id, I want to do it on the server instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to use are nested forms.

First you can tell your model to accept the nested attributes ([api for nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)),like

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
```

in your stock model.

Then in your form you can use fields_for ([api for fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)), to nest product fields into your stock form.
Imagine something like:

```
= form_for(@stock) do |form|
  = form.text_field :some_stock_attribute
  = form.fields_for(@stock.product) do |product_form|
     = product_form.text_field :prod_code
```

This essentially nests the name of your prod_code form field, to "stock[product_attributes][prod_code]", while, thanks to the accepts_nested_attributes_for, your stock model is prepared to pass the product_attributes to the associated product.

## Update (see comments):

A referenced_by method as you imagine, does not exist. Also you will have to take care of a bit more, then just changing the associated product. You will still want to display an error, if the prod_code doesn't exist, i assume.

Roughly you can add a virtual attribute to the stock, which allows your stock form to have a text_field :prod_code (add attr :prod_code to stock model).

Second, before validation you will probably need a method, that looks up the product for the prod_code, and changes the association, or adds an error on :prod_code.

this could look a bite like this:

```
class Stock
  attr :prod_code

  before_validation :associate_product_from_prod_code

  def associate_product_from_prod_code
    unless self.product = Product.where(:prod_code => prod_code)
      errors[:prod_code] << "Product Code is not valid"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.  What this would do is allow changing the prod_code on a product record.  What I am trying to do is use the prod_code to change the product_id that the stock record is linked to.  I'll amend the question since I think it may not be explained too well!

Comment: But you don't want to use a select field for the product_id, but instead have a text field for the user to enter the prod_code/

Comment: That looks pretty good, it is a more concise version of what I have currently got - the before_validation looks a very handy trick.  I am still hoping to find a way to put this code in the Product model though

Comment: you will not be able to put that on the product model. The Stock form is posted to the stock controller, and the Stock Model needs to associate itself with the product. If you have a working version of the code (i absolutely do not guarantee that my code works without any further issues), you can put it in a module though, so you'd only have to include one line in Stock and other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use prod_code instead of product_id as the foreign_key:

```
class Stock
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => "prod_code"
end
```

Or you can set it on Product:

```
class Product
  has_many :stocks, :foreign_key => "prod_code"
  has_many :images, :foreign_key => "prod_code"
  has_many :sizes,  :foreign_key => "prod_code"
end
```